# Excel C++ Communicator API : Access violation with _ChartPtr

Tags: c++, excel

I am implementing the Excel C++ Communicator API for exporting a graphic chart to an image file.

Below is the C++ code.

```
    // Launch Excel
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr spXlApp;
    HRESULT hr = spXlApp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Excel::Application));

    // Open sheet
    Excel::WorkbooksPtr spXlBooks = spXlApp->Workbooks;
    Excel::_WorkbookPtr spXlBook = spXlBooks->Open(L"D:\\Sample1.xlsx");
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr spXlSheet = spXlBook->Worksheets->Item[1];

    // Get chart
    Excel::ChartObjectPtr spXlChartObj = spXlSheet->ChartObjects(1);
    Excel::_ChartPtr spXlChart = spXlChartObj->Chart;

    // Everything is fine here. 
    // All pointers are valid (especially spXlChart)
    // and I do have the right chart selected.

    // Do things with Chart
    wprintf(L"%s\n", spXlChart->Name);
    spXlChart->Export(L"D:\\Chart.png");
```

Both **spXlChart->Name** and **spXlChart->Export** cause access violation. And the debugger stops at the get_Name line of the following code :

```
#pragma implementation_key(16574)
inline _bstr_t Excel::_Chart::GetName ( ) {
    BSTR _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = get_Name(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _bstr_t(_result, false);
}
```

I tried exactly the same operations with Tcom Excel and everything works fine.

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you

Comment: And all the pointers in *your* code look valid? Are the sheet and chart-object zero-based (like is the usual for arrays or array-like obhects in C++) or one-based? Are you getting the correct sheet and chart-object? Do you have any kind of error checking at all in your code?

Comment: I forgot to mention : all pointers are non-null and charts are 1 based. I removed all error checking code before posting here

Comment: No obvious mistakes, hard to guess what "Excel C++ Communicator" could mean.  I'd have to guess at a version mismatch, Microsoft has kept these COM interfaces binary compatible for over 18 years already and it is running out of steam.  Much less of a problem with Tcl because you'd be forced to use late binding.  Be sure to #import the correct type library and that it matches the version of Excel you are testing with.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right! Thank you for your comment. Please correct my answer if anything is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found : The #import statements did not reference the right Office version.

My program was based on [CppAutomateExcel samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateExcel-be36992e) which gave 2 solutions of Excel automation : #import and COM API.

I took the #import, which was written for Office 12, while I have Office 15 installed. That may be the reason for which some commands did not work.

I then took the COM API solution, which seems to be version independent. Everything now works fine.

Thanks for @Hans Passant's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
Excel::_ChartPtr spXlChart = (IUnknown*)spXlChartObj->Chart;
```

It's #import bug.